# DataTables draw() doesn't change display

Tags: javascript, draw, datatables-1.10

I'm stuck with something [that should be] pretty simple: after modifying the content of a cell, I can't make the change visible with `draw()`.

Here is a basical sample, showing the `DataTable().data()` before and after change, while the displayed table remains unchanged.

```
$('table').DataTable({
  data: [
  {a: 'A1', b: 'B1'},
  {a: 'A2', b: 'B2'}
  ],
  columns: [
    {data: 'a', title: 'A'},
    {data: 'b', title: 'B'}
  ]
});
var dt = $('table').DataTable();
  console.log('before:', dt.data()[0]);
$('button').click(function() {
  dt.row(0).data().a = 'XXX';
  dt.draw();
  console.log('after:', dt.data()[0]);
});
```

Sorry, it can't be executed with the SO snippet, which fires a lot of security errors before timing out.
But you can see it working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdadLhmo/).

NOTE: I also tried inserting `invalidate()` before `draw()`, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update custom cell ([DOC](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26823/cell-data-set-vs-row-data-d)):
https://jsfiddle.net/hdadLhmo/2/

```
$('table').DataTable({
  data: [
  {a: 'A1', b: 'B1'},
  {a: 'A2', b: 'B2'}
  ],
  columns: [
    {data: 'a', title: 'A'},
    {data: 'b', title: 'B'}
  ]
});
var dt = $('table').DataTable();
  console.log('before:', dt.data()[0]);
$('button').click(function() {
  dt.row(0).data().a = 'XXX';
  dt.draw();
  console.log('after:', dt.data()[0], dt.cell(0, 0).data('XXX'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this DOC link! As the OP noticed, _DataTables retains the object references, but not the array_ is the key information that missed in the basic doc.

Comment: thanks to your approve, i used this lib and really nice to implement